# A responsive live desktop 21.04 image produces a slow VM image

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, 21.04, cpu-load

When I boot up a live desktop ISO in Virtual Machine Manager (kvm/qemu), the live system is super snappy and when I look at the "Resources" in the [System monitor](https://apps.gnome.org/ps/app/gnome-system-monitor/) the 4 supplied cores are pretty much idle (RAM: 6GB, no problem).

Then I install the 21.04 desktop as "minimal". After the reboot the responsiveness experienced in the live ISO is not there anymore in the "true" VM. I can wait for hours, but it never changes.

The System monitor always shows a fairly high CPU load (~50% on all cores). When the System monitor window is minified, the CPU load **drops to idle**. When I look at it with top, the CPU time is spent in various kworker processes.

I don't make any adjustments to the VM. The ISO and the VM are on the same SSD. The system is an AMD Threadripper running Ubuntu 21.04 as well.

### How to reproduce

- Grab 21.04 desktop live ISO
- Create a new VM. I used ubuntu 20.10 as the next nearest known ubuntu to my kvm/qemu
- Run VM, Choose "live"
- Open Terminal, type something. Notice responsiveness
- Open System Monitor, check Resources/CPUs
- Now install with default settings except that I use LVM for partitioning
- Reboot
- Open "Terminal", notice lag when typing
- Run "top", notice kworker processes
- Open "System Monitor", notice CPU load
- Minify "System Monitor"
- Wait minutes or days
- Open "System Monitor" again, notice CPU load

Comment: I just tried Manjaro GNOME 21.1.3 -  I needed something quick - and this behaves well. System Monitor creates no load and the VM idles around 3% CPU load.